# Email address shows as empty with claimrow function

Tags: marketing-cloud, ampscript

Puzzled about Claimrow function. We are assigning unique codes to unique email addresses in a daily automation. We have one data extension that we send to, and another data extension that keeps the codes. We use ClaimRow function. From time to time, we have cases when the coupon shows as being claimed but the email address is null.

This is impossible, because the data extension we send to has email address as a primary key. In those weird situation, the code that is claimed but has null email address will always show a different claim date than the others on that day. For example, today we send at email at 8:38AM. All the coupons are shown as claimed at 8:38AM. But the one that's claimed with null email_address shows claimed date as 8:35AM.

We DO NOT do preview and test. This is a daily automation that we dont touch. Has anybody experienced anything like this before?
I have contacted support multiple times and they are super puzzled too and can't find the reason behind this.
I have opened a case, again.. But I am just curious if anyone else has ever experienced something like this before? 
Below is the code:

```
[var @em, @couponRow, @Sup_Code 

 set @em = AttributeValue("Email_Address") 
 set @couponRow = ClaimRow("ent.e_DE", "IsClaimed", "Email_Address", @em)IsNull(@Row) if not empty(@couponRow) then 
 set @Sup_Code = Field (@CouponRow, "Sup1") 
 else RaiseError("No coupons available", false) endif endif ]%%
```

The code data extension has fields of Sup1 as primary key, isClaimedDate as date (nullable), Email_address as nullable and isClaimed as boolean and nullable.

Comment: Can you please update your question to include the pertinent claimrow AMPscript code and the details of your coupon data extension fields?

Answer (score 0):

```
[var @em, @couponRow, @Sup_Code 

 set @em = AttributeValue("Email_Address") 
 set @couponRow = ClaimRow("ent.e_DE", "IsClaimed", "Email_Address", @em)IsNull(@Row) if not empty(@couponRow) then 
 set @Sup_Code = Field (@CouponRow, "Sup1") 
 else RaiseError("No coupons available", false) endif endif ]%%
```

The code data extension has fields of Sup1 as primary key, isClaimedDate as date (nullable), Email_address as nullable and isClaimed as boolean and nullable.

Comment: Hi @Emma, are you the poster of the original question? If so it would be better to edit your question.